# UIPageViewController with small pages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I've embedded a UIPageViewController (PVC), which fills the whole width of my screen size. I've created a child ViewController (VC) in my storyboard with a flexible size, in order to create a smaller VC than the PVC, believing that the size is fixed on runtime. When I'm adding the VC to the PVC the VC's size gets resized to fit the size of the PVC.

What I wanna do is, to build a PVC which has a look and feel like cards, represented by the child VC.

Does anyone know how to set the size of the child VC or has another idea, how to solve this?

Thanks!

PS: I've also tried to use a UICollectionView instead but this doesn't have the wanted sticky behaviour like a PVC.

[image]

Comment: have you used the Paging property for collection view to do this ?

Comment: you can use page controller for scroll view or collection view

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much @Maddyヅヅ - one checkmark in the storyboard solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As image show the `Paging Enabled` property in `collectionview` gives you the effect what exactly you are looking for, may this resolve your issue